# A question about installing kernels (related to running Hydrogen with Atom)

Tags: macos, python, kernel

I have a really basic question, but the more I read, the more confused I get: How do I install `pip` so I can install kernels?

This question came about when I tried to install the Hydrogen package to use in Atom, the text editor (to help me learn Python). I finally succeeded in installing Hydrogen, but got stumped by the missing kernels (not sure which ones I need, so I am willing to install them all). But I can't seem to install the kernels without `pip`.

I have a vague understanding of the implications of global vs local installations--I get that certain Python installations aren't compatible with local or global kernel installations (I hope I have the terminology right.) But I saw several warnings about installing pip for "a homebrew based python installation", but I am not sure whether Python on my laptop is installed via homebrew (nor how to find out).

So if Python(2.7) came pre-installed on my MacBook Pro (High Sierra), can I just do `sudo easy_install pip` (as suggested) from the command line--withOUT causing issues?

I first posted this question in StackExchange and was advised to seek help here. Frankly I wasn't sure whether this was a Mac question or a Atom question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Macs come with Python installed but most people use a different distribution.  Either Anaconda or Homebrew seems to be the most popular.

Comment: Have you tried using pip. it should already be installed on your mac.

Comment: Apparently pip is not installed. I followed the instructions to query whether pip had been installed and got "-bash: pip: command not found". So I was totally stumped.

Comment: PS: My Mac does have Python 2.7 installed, but no pip.

Comment: Thanks for your tip-it led me to instructions for "get-pip.py" (https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip). I am also wondering if I should just do an install of Python 3, which would come complete with pip.

Comment: command not found could be a path problem.  Have you tried typing 'which pip' and 'locate pip'?

Comment: i use virtual environments to run both python 2.7.13 and 3.6.  Works great for me but I used the Anaconda python distribution.

Comment: Before posting the question, I tried "which pip", but got no response--no pip. Tried "locate pip" just now, and got a warning "The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist." I think I am going to go ahead and install Python 3 and maybe that will solve the problem.

Comment: Can you please post the solution as an answer below (and accept it) instead of adding it to the question?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by making the first line of my script:

```
#!path/to/python
```

I type `which python` and use the result in first line of script. Now Hydrogen works every time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem of installing `pip`-but it is NOT a perfect solution because I discovered Hydrogen sometimes kicks in and sometimes not--this relates to my initial concern about global/local installations. But here's how I installed `pip`; perhaps others can help resolve the rest.

1. Install Python 3 (from python.org).
2. Follow instructions to get 'get-pip.py' (https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#ensure-you-can-run-pip-from-the-command-line). (This was done from the terminal)
3. In Atom, cmd+shift+p to bring up the packages menu; click on 'Hydrogen Run'. When the errors message pops up,copy the code from the error warnings, go back to the terminal, and install the kernels needed (via the command line).
4. At this point, Hydrogen is now working.
5. BUT: in Atom, sometimes Hydrogen works, sometimes it doesn't. So it's not stable.